# Хвороб чи хворіб?

Tags: відмінювання, родовий-відмінок

Побачила на різних сайтах такі формулювання: "Картини **хворіб** і лікування" ([Клініка Піраварт](https://www.klinik-pirawarth.at/uk/kartini-hvorib-i-likuvannya/)), "5 **хворіб**, в боротьбі з якими корисно пити каву" ([Українські новини](https://ukranews.com/ua/news/475291-5-khvorib-v-borotbi-z-yakymy-korysno-pyty-kavu)) та "Перелік інфекційних **хвороб** людини" ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA_%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8)), "Симптоми **хвороб** - зовнішні ознаки захворювань від А до Я" ([Eurolab](http://www.eurolab.ua/symptomsua/)).
Теоретично мало б бути чергування *хвороба - хворіб* за аналогією *дорога - доріг* і ця форма мала б бути правильною.

Отже, то яка із форм є правильною: хвороб чи хворіб? Що зумовило широке використання помилки?

Comment: Мені здається суттєвою відмінністю між «дорога» і «хвороба» те, що в «дорога» оце «-ог-» — це частина кореня, а в «хвороба» — суфікс «-об-» («хворіти»; аналогічно «жалоба», «шаноба», «злоба», «худоба», «знадоба») — але підтвердження не бачив.

Comment: @Sasha цьікаво, шчо згаданиь ві відповідьі словник не маье множини дльа «аналоґічних слі».

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У [Словниках онлайн](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (Орфографічний словник) знаходимо:

> ВІДМІНОК  ОДНИНА  МНОЖИНА
>   Називний - хвороба,   хвороби.
>   Родовий - хвороби,    хвороб.
>   Давальний - хворобі,  хворобам.
>   Знахідний - хворобу,  хвороби.
>   Орудний - хворобою, хворобами.
>   Місцевий - хворобі,   на/у хворобах.
>   Кличний - хворобо,    хвороби.

Отже, правильно: Р. В. мнж. слова "хвороба" - хвороб.

Також знаходимо у [Культура \ Мова \ Проблеми мови](http://www.chasipodii.net/article/5974/) таке:

> 2.??? хвороб чи хворіб
>
> В сполученнях -оро-, -оло-, -ере-, -еле- (т.зв. "повноголосся": голос,
>   мороз, шелест, очерет) о, е переходять в і:
>
> 1) у родовому відмінку множини іменників жіночого роду (здебільшого з
>   рухомим наголосом) і в похідних від них іменниках на -к(а) зі
>   значенням зменшеності: борода- борід- борідка, голова- голів- голівка
>   (і головка- з іншим значенням), сторона- сторін- сторінка. 2) у
>   родовому відмінку множини іменників здебільшого середнього роду й
>   відповідних зменшених іменниках: болото- боліт- болітце, ворота-
>   воріт- ворітця, долото- доліт- долітце, але: дерево- дерев- деревце,
>   джерело- джерел- джерельце;
>
> Винятки: a. поріг, моріг, оборіг, сморід;
>
> Чергування о, е з і не відбувається:
>
> О, е в закритому складі не переходять в І 1) у повноголосних формах
>   -оро-, -оло- ере-, -еле зі сталим наголосом іменників переважно жіночого роду, від яких немає зменшених форм з і: колоди -колод
>   (колодка), долоні - долонь (долонька); сороки - сорок, огорожі -
>   огорож, нагорода - нагород

Іменник "хвороба" -ж.р.,сталий наголос,"О, е в закритому складі не переходять в І 1) у повноголосних формах -оро-, -оло- ере-, -еле зі сталим наголосом іменників переважно жіночого роду, від яких немає зменшених форм ".

А помилково вживають, тому що, відміняють за аналогією до "боліт, воріт" і інших, не враховуючи інших мовних нюансів.

Comment: Але ж «дорога» теж має бути під тим самим правилом, що й «хвороба», хіба ні?

Comment: але ми тоді не можемо сказати "дорог". А за автором відповіді кажемо "хвороб". Чи я не правильно зрозуміла?

Comment: До речі, те, що Ви цитуєте з «Культура \ Мова \ Проблеми мови» — це фактично [«Правопис»](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par8p3b1) — тож, може, варто прямо туди посилання надати, а не на «Культура \ Мова \ Проблеми мови» (але там усе заплутане, це не єдиний пункт, що має стосунок на нашого питання)?

Comment: дорога - у пестливі формі мало б бути "дорожка" за цією аналогією. Але за законом відкритого складу"дорожька" "о"  через стадію дифтонгізації переходить в "і".-доріжка-доріг. Цього не маємо у слові "хвороба", оскільки -оро-це повноголосся, а не "о", яке походить з ь(йор). Тому до слова "дорога" не можемо це правило достосувати  [Купчинська З., Пілецький В. Історична граматика української мови](https://www.twirpx.com/file/2163787/)

Comment: Цьікаво, шчо при цьому Польська, де також ті зміни з **о** на вже **у**, маьу зміну, тобто *choroba > chorób* (чит.  ьак *хороба > хоруб*). До того ж, цитата мовить про пньа, а не родового відмінку, цебто нема заперечень і не бачу сенсу в тому, чому відповідь затверджена, до того ж: _особа > осіб_.

Comment: В слові "хвороба" нема того повноголосся, про яке каже стаття: в прасловʼянському корені вже було друге "о". Тому етимологічно правильно - "хворіб". Але процеси вирівнювання могли створити іншу схему відмінювання.

Answer (score 1):

[Правопис [2019]](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=10) наводить [**хвороб**](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=90).

> б) назви почуттів, **хвороб**: …

Саме правило:

> #### Відхилення в чергуванні О — І, Е — І
>
> 3. Є багато позицій, коли чергування **о**, **е** з **і** у відкритих і закритих
>      складах немає всупереч наведеним правилам:
>
> 3. 2. у групах **-оро-**, **-оло-**, **-ере-** **о**, **е** переходять в **і**:
>
>       - у родовому відмінку множини іменників жіночого роду (здебільшого
>           з рухомим наголосом) і в похідних від них іменниках на **-к-(а)** зі значенням
>           зменшеності: *борода́ — борі́д — борі́дка, борона́ — борі́н — борі́нка, голова́ — голі́в — голі́вка* (і *голо́вка* — з іншим значенням), *сторона́ — сторі́н — сторі́нка, череда́ — чері́д — чері́дка*;
>       - у родовому відмінку множини іменників здебільшого середнього роду й відповідних іменниках зі значенням зменшеності: *боло́то — болі́т — болі́тце, воро́та — ворі́т — ворі́тця, долото́ — долі́т — долі́тце*, але: *де́рево — дере́в — деревце́*, *джерело́ — джере́л — джере́льце*;
>
> 3. 5. **о, е** наявні в закритому складі:
>
>       - у повноголосних формах **-оро-, -оло-** зі сталим наголосом іменників
>           переважно жіночого роду: *коло́д (коло́дка), доло́нь (доло́нька), соро́к, огоро́ж,
>           моро́к, нагоро́д* (від них немає зменшених форм з **і**). Але: *дорі́г, дорі́жка, корі́в, корі́вка, бері́з, бері́зка* (проте *бере́зка* — виткий бур’ян);

Comment: Але далі йде 5) о, е наявні в закритому складі: ... б) у повноголосних формах -оро-, -оло- зі сталим наголосом іменників
переважно жіночого роду: коло́д (коло́дка), доло́нь (доло́нька), соро́к, огоро́ж,
моро́к, нагоро́д (від них немає зменшених форм з і). Але: дорі́г, дорі́жка,
корі́в, корі́вка, бері́з, бері́зка (проте бере́зка — виткий бур’ян);
в) у родовому відмінку множини деяких іменників переважно жіночого
роду: будо́в, вод, істо́т, осно́в, підпо́р, проб, субо́т, топо́ль, шкод; леле́к,
меж, озе́р, потре́б, але: осі́б, підкі́в;